# USB port from Host device is not charging the charging cable is getting hot and burnt colleagues laptop

Tags: usb, port, charging

USB host device has an HSD connector, which is connected to USB 2 port with a length of cable about 2 meters.

When I connect my phone for charging, I can feel the USB cable get hot and phone does not charge. I tried connecting my headset microphone with it, which has a small led which should light up when connected. that doesn't work either, but when I connect the same headset to my laptop it works.

I hv measured 5v on pin 1 (USB conector) with respect to GND on pin 4. Can there be a short on D+ and D- or 5v amd GND are inverted.

Comment: It doesn't need deep investigation, it just needs throwing away.

Comment: This. Cable is broken, likely has an internal short.  I am usually in favour of repairing, but this is easier to throw away and buy a new cable.

Comment: But the issue is when I use the same cable with my laptop, it works. And the MPOW headset USB cable also works with my laptop port. so I can understand one charging cable is flaky but hard to imagine head set usb cable is also faulty, when its actually working perfect.